# Notice: Undefined offset: 0...25

Tags: php

```
$score = 0;
$topics = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($user_responses); $i++) {
    if ( ((int)$user_responses[$i]['response'])+((int)$mismatch_responses[$i]['response']) == 3 ){
        $score += 1;
        array_push($topics, $user_responses[$i]['topic_name']);
    }
}
```

It's appear

Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Notice: Undefined offset: 2

....

Notice: Undefined offset: 25

can anybody help me?

Thanks...

Comment: what is inside $user_responses. can you do a print_r($user_responses)

Comment: Undefined offset means you array key does not exist. Im guessing that there is problem with array $mismatch_responses[$i]

Comment: what does var_dump($user_responses) show?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 53 [response_id] => 53 [1] => 1 [topic_id] => 1 [2] => 2 [response] => 2 [3] => Tattoos [topic_name] => Tattoos ) 

Sometghin like this@@

Comment: array (size=26)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '53' (length=2)
      'response_id' => string '53' (length=2)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      'topic_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      'response' => string '2' (length=1)
      3 => string 'Tattoos' (length=7)
      'topic_name' => string 'Tattoos' (length=7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things in this case. Change the error reporting to 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE' so you won't be bothered with this messages. Or use the 'isset' function to check if a variable exists.

I think you problem lays here:

```
if ( ((int)$user_responses[$i]['response'])+((int)$mismatch_responses[$i]['response']) == 3 ){
```

you should first check if both variables exists, and use it if they do:

```
if (!isset($user_responses[$i]['response']) || !isset($mismatch_responses[$i]['response'])) continue; //skips the loop if one of the variables does not exist

if ( ((int)$user_responses[$i]['response'])+((int)$mismatch_responses[$i]['response']) == 3 ){
```

Comment: Then it will appear Notice: Undefined offset: i

@@

Comment: What code did you use to set the error reporting level? Oh btw, the second solution is better ;)